# Apache Ivy custom resolver

Tags: ivy

One of the projects which I work with uses Apache ivy to resolve dependencies. So far all 3rd components were deployed as Maven packages, however, now I have to get a NuGet package instead. As ivy does not support NuGet I'd like to write my own resolver. Is this possible? I've looked over the net but did not find any documentation on this.

Comment: Yes, the ['resolvers' settings documentation page](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/resolvers.html) says "If you don’t find the one you want here, you can also check if someone has contributed it on the links page, or even write your own." I'd copy IvyRepResolver, i.e. write a class that extends URL resolver, put it in an Ivy plugin and then you should be able to reference it from the settings.

Comment: S... I've looked at this page at least a few times and did not notice that. Could you put it as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: OK, thanks, can do. it's more of a steer in the right direction / guess than an answer though! will see if I can flesh it out a bit. Or happy for you to self-answer if that works / once you've fleshed out what you need to do.

Comment: It's more than I needed :) All the info is right there now is just coding :D